# Clone sharepoint list converting calculated values

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for the way to clone/duplicate sharepint list but in a new list I need  all calculated fields to be just numbers - is there any way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can export the list to Excel the use the "Create List from Excel" option to upload the Excel file as a new list.  The calculated columns should convert to text.